# Subplot's center plot scales strangely in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, subplot

I'm plotting data from 9 different sources to a subplot in Matlab. Here you can see my figure:

[image]

Each row is representing results for a certain variable under different conditions. So row 1 is variable 1, second row variable 2 etc. Anyway, as you can see from the picture the center plot scales strangely in comparison with the other two in the second row.

The code I have used includes the use of commands such as: `subplot(3,3,i), imagesc(data), colorbar, colormap(flipud(gray)), title('sometitle'), caxis([limits])`

I tried to fix the center plot by setting the y-limits using `ylim([0.5 3.5])`, but this had no effect...when I tried `ylim([0 4])` this happened:

[image]

Note that the data in the plots in each row have equal size matrices. In row 1: 7-by-7 matrix, in row 2: 3-by-3 matrix and in row 3: 4-by-4 matrix.

How can I resolve this issue? :)

Thank you for any help!

UPDATE:

Here is what happened after I tried using the commands:

```
subplot(3,3,5)
imagesc(data)
axis square
colorbar
```

[image]

Here is a minimum working example: (It apparently does not give exactly the same results, but still there is similar issues with it as well):

```
data11 = rand(7,7);
data12 = rand(7,7);
data13 = rand(7,7);
data21 = rand(3,3);
data22 = rand(3,3);
data23 = rand(3,3);
data31 = rand(4,4);
data32 = rand(4,4);
data33 = rand(4,4);
subplot(3,3,1)
imagesc(data11)
colorbar
colormap(flipud(gray))
title('title')
subplot(3,3,2)
imagesc(data12)
colorbar
colormap(flipud(gray))
title('title')
subplot(3,3,3)
imagesc(data13)
colorbar
colormap(flipud(gray))
title('title')
subplot(3,3,4)
imagesc(data21)
colorbar
title('title')
subplot(3,3,5)
imagesc(data22)
colorbar
title('title')
subplot(3,3,6)
imagesc(data23)
colorbar
title('title')
subplot(3,3,7)
imagesc(data31)
colorbar
title('title')
subplot(3,3,8)
imagesc(data32)
colorbar
title('title')
subplot(3,3,9)
imagesc(data33)
colorbar
title('title')
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Notice that I inputted the commands individually (command + enter, command + enter, etc.) and then I get the problem, i.e. the picture you see in this post. If I copy and paste the whole code (whole code + enter) I don't get any problems...

Comment: try adding `axis square` after `imagesc` and see if that solves it.

Comment: I dont know why this happens, but what could help, is to set the yticks directly

Comment: +1 Thnx @natan for the help, I added the results to post. No help :(

Comment: can you give a minimal working example so we could see if we get the same behavior ?

Comment: @natan yes I can, give me few mins :)

Comment: @natan MWE added :) Not very optimized code, but it will do the trick and it mimics the same procedure I used to get my original problem :)

Comment: the output of your code looks fine in my machine (matlab 2012a on win-7 64). I can't seem to recreate the bug you are having.

Comment: @natan I noticed the exact same thing! :O You know I discovered (this is strange...) when I copy and paste the code straight to Matlab and press Enter I don't get the problem. But If I set those commands individually (command + enter, etc.) I get the problem?!...Try that...If you get the same result...

Comment: sorry to say, it still works fine on my machine.

Comment: @natan Hmm, strange :) Well I think I got it. I just have to copy and paste the whole code and run all at once rather than set them individually. For some reason I get the problem If I do this...thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to set the 'ActivePositionProperty' for each axis to 'Position'  See the documentation on [axes properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) for details.

```
 h1 = subplot(3,3,1);
 set(h1,'ActivePositionProperty','Position');

 h2 = subplot(3,3,2);
 set(h2,'ActivePositionProperty','Position');
```

If that doesn't work you will need to set the position property for each plot manually.

```
 Margin = 0.1
 Width = 1 - 4*Margin;
 Height = 1 - 4*Margin;
 Left = [ (Margin) (2*Margin+Width) (3*Margin+2*Width) ];
 Bottom = [ (Margin) (2*Margin+Height) (3*Margin+2*Height) ];

 h1 = subplot(3,3,1);
 set(h1,'Position', [Left(1) Bottom(3) Width Height]);

 h2 = subplot(3,3,2);
 set(h1,'Position', [Left(2) Bottom(3) Width Height]);

 h3 = subplot(3,3,2);
 set(h1,'Position', [Left(3) Bottom(3) Width Height]);

 h4 = subplot(3,3,2);
 set(h1,'Position', [Left(1) Bottom(2) Width Height]);

 %Etc
```